# Unable to connect to Template Builder : Username must be specified

Tags: 2013-sp1, template-builder

I m currently facing an issue with my newly created Tridion CME while connecting to the Template Builder.
I downloaded it from the new CME and when i try to connect using the ip i get "Username must be specified error" .This error doesn't pop for other environments.

Please let me know if i missed any configurations.

[image]

Below are the error details

```
User name must be specified.
```

Message--User name must be specified.
ErrorCode--770
StackFrame method="LoadAccessToken" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager"
StackFrame method=".ctor" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Session"
StackFrame method="Initialize" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebServiceStackFrame method="Login" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.Login(Boolean initData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Model.Login(Uri contentManager, NetworkCredential credentials)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UI.CompoundTemplateDesigner.DesignerForm.LogonAs(Uri uri, Exception initialError)

Comment: Hi Andrey , Updated with the details

Comment: Are you able to browse the same environment in the browser using the same username, you are passing to template builder?

Comment: Is it SSO or LDAP? You said you are trying to connect using IP, does it work if connect using machine name?

Comment: Yes i'm able to browse and see all the publications for the same environment.

Comment: It is LDAP and when connecting using Machine name also gives me same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LDAP is misconfigured, double check all the settings. To find out what is wrong, you may use fiddler and see which webservice is having the wrong the configuration.

Comment: Thanks Andrey and Dommelan, Issue is resolved after reconfiguring the LDAP

Answer (score 1):

When using LDAP authentication there are several WCF related configuration files that need to be adjusted. It would appear at least one of them was missed during the original setup and configuration.

Your best option is to re-follow the documentation steps for setting up LDAP authentication (as this might not be the only problem you will run into later).

If that is too much at the moment focus on the *.config files in the TemplateBuilder application root folder.