# Unable to connect to Template Builder in newly installed Tridion 2013

Tags: template-builder

I have configured Siteminder for the user authentication as per the documentation provided to me. Tridion GUI is working fine with that configuration, but I am unable to connect to the Template Builder.
[image: Error Message]

Below are the error details -

```
<detail>
<Message>
<Line>User name must be specified.</Line>
</Message>
<ErrorCode>770</ErrorCode>
<StackTrace>
<StackFrame method="LoadAccessToken" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager" />
<StackFrame method=".ctor" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Session" />
<StackFrame method="Initialize" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" />
<StackFrame method="Login" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.WebService.CompoundTemplateWebService" />
</StackTrace>
</detail>
```

Please let me know if i missed any configurations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to Template Builder : Username must be specified](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/unable-to-connect-to-template-builder-username-must-be-specified)

Comment: It likely is a duplicate, but as Payel's first question, I'd like to confirm this is the same issue. Payel, see if it's LDAP as Andrey described in the other post. If it is, let us know and we can point this question to the other one, by closing it. This lets future Tridion Stack Exchange members find the right answer in fewer places. If it's not LDAP, also let us know so we can investigate further.

Comment: Payel has specified Siteminder.. so it's SSO rather than LDAP. The issues will be similar though.

Answer (score 1):

I know we had a battle with Siteminder when trying to use Content Porter. you may have the same issue. This might help as a start:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2013/concept_2EC3CFDC14344CFC9E250BE5DE0EC268

SDL support helped us get things (mostly) working. we still have to toggle Siteminder off to get it to work.